# Unable to create Android Monogame Android Project in visual studio 2010

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, monogame

I am unable to create the monogame project in visual studio ultimate 2010, I am also sharing the screen shots of the my steps as follows

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

People already raised this question but no appropriate answer was provided.

sln in text file

**Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00

## Visual Studio 2010

Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal**

Comment: Would you please open the `.csproj` file with a text editor and include it to your question?

Comment: I am not able to create one, that what I am trying to do

Comment: Is there any file called `MonoGameTestProject.csproj` in that location or not? Second screenshot.

Comment: I am sorry, you were right, it was there and i have edited it already in the question

Comment: Have you installed [Xamarin Visual Studio Extension](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid)?